# Use Flume to stream a webpage data to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, flume, cloudera-cdh

I have 3 node cluster, using latest cloudera parcels for 5.9 version. OS is CentOS 6.7 on all three of them. I am using Flume for the first time.

My purpose is to stream webpage data into HDFS. However this webpage is a third party website, news site in my case so I don't know which Port to use to connect.

Curl and telnet was happening on port 80, hence i used it. But getting error.

My Flume.conf is:

```
tier1.sources  = http-source
tier1.channels = mem-channel-1
tier1.sinks    = hdfs-sink
tier1.sources.http-source.type     = http
tier1.sources.http-source.handler = org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler
tier1.sources.http-source.bind     = 132.247.1.32
tier1.sources.http-source.port     = 80
tier1.sources.http-source.channels = mem-channel-1
tier1.channels.mem-channel-1.type   = memory
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.type         = hdfs
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel      = mem-channel-1
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path    = /flume/events/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
# Other properties are specific to each type of
# source, channel, or sink. In this case, we
# specify the capacity of the memory channel.
tier1.channels.mem-channel-1.capacity = 100
```

**Error**

```
2016-12-19 16:45:00,353 WARN org.mortbay.log: failed SelectChannelConnector@132.247.1.32:80: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
2016-12-19 16:45:00,353 WARN org.mortbay.log: failed Server@36772002: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
2016-12-19 16:45:00,353 ERROR org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource: Error while starting HTTPSource. Exception follows.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address**
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart2016-12-19 16:45:00,364 ERROR org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{
name:http-source,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address(SelectChannelConnector.java:315)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.start(HTTPSource.java:207)
at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the source config as below :
    httpagent.sources.http-source.port = 80
    httpagent.sources.http-source.bind = localhost
    httpagent.sources.http-source.url = 132.247.1.32

Note : If 132.247.1.32 doesn't work, try giving the hostname.

Comment: I implemented the suggestion given by you.Thanks.Now there is no error in the Flume log and I can see **http-source started**
However nothing is streaming into HDFS Flume path. Do you think by changing http-source.bind to local host, it has configured its own server as its source?My flume.conf part looks like this now-
`tier1.sources.http-source.bind     = localhost
tier1.sources.http-source.url = http://www.jornada.unam.mx/ultimas
tier1.sources.http-source.port     = 5440`
PS : changed port from 80 to 5440 because even after opening the port  80 on server. it was giving bind exception.

Comment: Apart from this, my hdfs sink path looks like this `tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path    = hdfs://lnxmasternode01.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/flume/events/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S`
no streaming happening - 
`-bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -ls /flume
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - flume hdfs          0 2016-12-23 11:49 /flume/events
-bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -ls /flume/events
-bash-4.1$`
Please help!

Comment: As, I said there is no data streaing happening.I checked the flume jars for source, I can find only these with cloudera bundle:
`[hadoop@LnxMasterNode01 jars]$ ll flume*source*
flume-avro-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-jms-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-kafka-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-scribe-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-taildir-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-thrift-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-twitter-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar`
Can this be the reason why http source is not working despite no error in flume.log? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP source for Flume provides a way to use GET/POST to send data into a flume agent. The HTTP source does not go out and fetch data from websites for you, it sets up a HTTP server and waits for GET/POST and accepts the data from that endpoint.

My recommendation would be to create a custom source that fetches the webpage you require.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.Do you think it would be good if I schedule a CRON using CURL to get the webpage content and save it in a file everytime. Make a Flume netcat source for the files and hdfs sink? Can you guide me if not this then how to make a custom source. I am new in this. Please

Comment: any help please??

Comment: I checked the flume jars for source, I can find only these with cloudera bundle:
`[hadoop@LnxMasterNode01 jars]$ ll flume*source*
flume-avro-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-jms-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-kafka-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-scribe-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-taildir-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-thrift-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar
flume-twitter-source-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar`
Can this be the reason why http source is not working i.e. data streaming not happening despite no error in flume.log and it says **http-source started**? Please suggest

Comment: Check out [Flume Custom Source Documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#source)

Specifically the line "Event e = getSomeData();"

Implement the getSomeData() method to fetch the HTML.

You can do pre-processing on it or just send it through as is.

Compile this and make sure it ends up on Flumes classpath. (I do this by dropping it in the lib directory but your distribution may be different)

Then in your agent configuration 
tier1.sources.http-source.type     =  $FULL_CLASS_NAME